# constructing an analytic function from another analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ open and let $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ analytic and $z \in U$. Then the function
$$
g(w)= \begin{cases}\frac{f(w)-f(z)}{w-z} & \text { if } z \neq w \\ f^{\prime}(z) & \text { if } w=z .\end{cases}
$$
is analytic in $U$.

I tried a bunch of ideas for this. First, I tried to use cauchy-riemann equations but honestly it's so hard to get it when $w \neq z$.

Another idea I was trying was to use the limits definition and showing that $\lim_{w\to z} \frac{\frac{f(w)-f(z)}{w-z}-f'(z)}{w-z}=g'(w)$ but not successful again.

Finally, I ended up writing $f$ as power series expansion which I think should work but I don't know where am I going with it. This is to write $f$ as $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(w-z)^n$, so $f(w)-f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(w-z)^n$ and hence, we can define $g(z)$ to be $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+1}(w-z)^n$ which is basically $\frac{f(w)-f(z)}{w-z}$ and I'm guessing it's analytic cause $f$ is analytic but IDK how to prove it rigorously.

Comment: I am fairly sure that this has been asked and answered before, but the [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz) search engine is currently down. – It suffices to show that $\lim_{w \to z} g(w) = f'(z) = g(z)$, then apply Riemann's theorem on removable singularities.

Comment: @MartinR The thing is we haven't covered that theorem and singularities in the class.

Comment: Then show that  $g(w) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+1}(w-z)^n$ has the same radius of convergence as $f(w) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(w-z)^n$.